# PE: Strange entry in debug directory (Type: 0xc)

Tags: pe, binary-format, debugging-symbols

Microsoft describes the IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY structure [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680307(v=vs.85).aspx).

I learned [here](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debuginfomatch.html#debuginfoinpe) that for recent VisualStudio-compiled binaries, the type is `IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW`, i.e. the value is `0x2`.

Now I have a vanilla VS-2015 compiled binary and I am using the Python module `pefile` to iterate over the `IMAGAE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY` objects:

```
for debug_data_object in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DEBUG:
    ...
```

The first entry is as expected:

```
0x6500     0x0   Characteristics:               0x0       
0x6504     0x4   TimeDateStamp:                 0x59088504 [Tue May 02 13:09:24 2017 UTC]
0x6508     0x8   MajorVersion:                  0x0       
0x650A     0xA   MinorVersion:                  0x0       
0x650C     0xC   Type:                          0x2       
0x6510     0x10  SizeOfData:                    0x88      
0x6514     0x14  AddressOfRawData:              0x176DC   
0x6518     0x18  PointerToRawData:              0x66DC
```

But there is a second one. Its type is 0xC :

```
0x651C     0x0   Characteristics:               0x0       
0x6520     0x4   TimeDateStamp:                 0x59088504 [Tue May 02 13:09:24 2017 UTC]
0x6524     0x8   MajorVersion:                  0x0       
0x6526     0xA   MinorVersion:                  0x0       
0x6528     0xC   Type:                          0xC       
0x652C     0x10  SizeOfData:                    0x14      
0x6530     0x14  AddressOfRawData:              0x17764   
0x6534     0x18  PointerToRawData:              0x6764
```

What is this second entry about? Why is it there? What does type `0xc` correspond to?

**UPDATE**

In addition to the answer below, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48723533/4480139) SO post contains additional detailed info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check `winnt.h` from the latest Windows 10 SDK you can find rest of the values there:

```
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_UNKNOWN          0
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_COFF             1
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW         2
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_FPO              3
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_MISC             4
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_EXCEPTION        5
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_FIXUP            6
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_OMAP_TO_SRC      7
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_OMAP_FROM_SRC    8
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_BORLAND          9
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_RESERVED10       10
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CLSID            11
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE       12
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_POGO             13
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_ILTCG            14
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_MPX              15
#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_REPRO            16
```

So `0xC` is `IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE`. It looks like there's not much info on what it is stored there but you can do some searches to get some idea.

Comment: Not much info about `IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE`, indeed. I will post a new question at stackoverflow, maybe somebody knows more about `IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE`.